# Build failed: "ld: library not found for -lPods-ChatSecure"

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, cocoapods

I'm getting following error when building the app.

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-ChatSecure
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help me.

I'm stuck here.

Comment: Are you using the .xcodeproj file instead of the .xcworkspace file?

Comment: @Kerberos  -no... I'm using .xcworkspace file